# MySQL: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql

Trying to execute this below query on MySQL:

```
update comm_store set flag = 'D' and stores in('EU','AUS','US', 
'CHN') where emp_id in(select emp_id from comm_store_sec)
```

but getting:

MySQL: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value 'D'

flag has datatype varchar
emp_id has BIGINT

Not betting how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the flag column data type?

then, change the sql like this

```
update comm_store set flag = 'D' , stores in('EU','AUS','US', 'CHN') where emp_id in(select emp_id from comm_store_sec)
```

Just changed the 'and' to ','
I did test on mariadb. succeeded

Comment: flag has datatype varchar and emp_id has BIGINT